# How to open PCD file

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I'm working with my kinect to extract point clouds. So I run at first openni_launch and after i run : rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/camera/depth_registered/points
So after this, ROS saves every point clouds that kinect gets. SO my question is: how can I extract data from a PCD? I want to extract fields about sensor_msgs/PointField[].
It exists another method to get every information about a PCD file?
thanks to all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228519/how-to-open-pcd-file/) by [kalum](https://answers.ros.org/users/26067/kalum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-09**:
If you installed pcl library you can use

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
```

otherwise use

```
#include <pcl_ros/io/pcd_io.h>
```

with the following command

```
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud)
```

**Comment by [kalum](https://answers.ros.org/users/26067/kalum/) on 2016-03-10**:
Thanks man!! I've another question. Is there a method to discover the distance between my image/object and my kinect? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use PCL. Check this tutorial; http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded "
            << cloud->width * cloud->height
            << " data points from test_pcd.pcd with the following fields: "
            << std::endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i)
    std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalum](https://answers.ros.org/users/26067/kalum/) on 2016-03-10**:
Thanks man!! I've another question. Is there a method to discover the distance between my image/object and my kinect? Thank you :)